How to handle react component being unmounted on user press in unit testing
I am writing Jest tests for my react native application. When I use user.press function, I get the following error:

Unable to find node on an unmounted component.

 at findCurrentFiberUsingSlowPath (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:574:13)
 at ReactTestInstance._currentFiber (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:18325:17)
 at ReactTestInstance.get (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:18397:19)
 at props (node_modules/@testing-library/react-native/src/user-event/utils/dispatch-event.ts:25:26)
 at getEventHandler (node_modules/@testing-library/react-native/src/user-event/utils/dispatch-event.ts:12:19)
 at emitTextPressEvents (node_modules/@testing-library/react-native/src/user-event/press/press.ts:125:16)
 at basePress (node_modules/@testing-library/react-native/src/user-event/press/press.ts:45:5)
 at Object.press (node_modules/@testing-library/react-native/src/user-event/press/press.ts:17:3)
 at wrapAsync (node_modules/@testing-library/react-native/src/helpers/wrap-async.ts:19:22)


The problem is that when I click a button, it triggers a state update, which unmounts that button from the element tree.
This is the minimal example to reproduce that error:
React component
export function TestComponent(): JSX.Element {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);

  return <View>{isVisible && <Text onPress={() => setIsVisible(false)}>Press_me</Text>}</View>;
}

Test file
import { render, screen, userEvent } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import { TestComponent } from '../App';
import { it } from '@jest/globals';

it('fails successfully', async () => {
  render(<TestComponent />);
  const user = userEvent.setup();
  await user.press(screen.getByText('Press_me'));
});

I found that I can avoid the error by using fireEvent instead of user.press:
import { render, screen, fireEvent, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import { TestComponent } from '../App';
import { it, expect } from '@jest/globals';

it('fails successfully', async () => {
  render(<TestComponent />);
  fireEvent.press(screen.getByText('Press_me'));
});

The component works fine on itself, and I would like to use user.press for consistency and better interaction simulation. Is there any way to make user.press work without errors?

Try to store the text component to a variable and press it: Ex const textCom = screen.getByText('Press_me'); await user.press(textCom);

Tried it, but got the same result.
